# Matlab spdiag no funciona como espero

Tags: matlab

Estoy intentando hacer una matriz nxn diagonal superior de la forma:
(d0 es la diagonal principal de la matriz, d1 la superior a esta, d2 la superior a d1, etc)

```
d0 = (n, n-1, n-2, ... , 2, 1)
d1 = (n-1, n-2, ... , 2, 1)
d2 = (n-2, n-3, ... , 2, 1)
.
.
.
dn-1 = (2 1)
dn = (1)

Ejemplo:

5 4 3 2 1
0 4 3 2 1
0 0 3 2 1
0 0 0 2 1
0 0 0 0 1
```

Esta es mi funcion, estoy usando spdiags de matlab

```
function [A] = P1a(n)
B = [];
for i=1:n
    v = flip(1:n-i+1);
    v(end+1:n)=0;
    B = [B; v]
end
A = spdiags(B, 0:(n-1), n, n);
end
```

el output es esto para n = 10, no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.

```
10     8     6     4     2     0     0     0     0     0
 0     9     7     5     3     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     8     6     4     2     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     7     5     3     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     6     4     2     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     5     3     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     4     2     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en la documentación de [spdiags](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html#mw_6de431d3-8887-4b16-b947-86a610ddea8c).

`A = spdiags(B,d,m,n)` crea una matriz dispersa de orden `mxn`, tomando las columnas de `B` y colocando estas sobre las diagonales especificadas por `d`.

Hay que tener en cuenta que las columnas de `B` tienen una longitud constante mientras que las diagonales de `A` no, entonces, obviamente hay elementos que van a ser ignorados al pasar cada columna a la diagonal correspondiente, el detalle es que los elementos ignorados dependerán del orden de la matriz.

Siendo la matriz `A` de `mxn` los elementos que se copiaran de la columna de `B` a la diagonal de `A` cumplen:

1. Para `m>=n`

   - Las diagonales bajo la diagonal principal toman primero los elementos de la parte superior de las columnas.
   - Las diagonales sobre la diagonal principal toman primero los elementos de la parte inferior de las columnas.
2. Este comportamiento se invierte cuando `m<n`:

Como ves, esta función tiene sus peculiaridades, en tu caso por ser una matriz cuadrada se cumple `m>=n`, por lo que las diagonales sobre de la diagonal principal se llenarán tomando primero los elementos de la parte inferior de las columnas.

La función `P1a` para `n=10`, crea la siguiente matriz `B`:

```
B =

    10     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0
     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0
     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0
     6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0
     5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Al usar `A = spdiags(B, 0:(10-1), 10, 10);`, se toma cada columna de `B` para colocarla en la respectiva diagonal de `A` ,especificada, en este caso, por el rango `0:(10-1)`, que indica diagonales sobre la diagonal principal, y ya que la matriz es cuadrada (se cumple `m>=n`), se tomará primero los elementos de la parte inferior. Esto explica el porqué tu función arroja ese resultado.

Entonces para obtener un resultado correcto, `B` debería tomar esta forma:

```
B =

    10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     9     9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     8     8     8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     7     7     7     7     0     0     0     0     0     0
     6     6     6     6     6     0     0     0     0     0
     5     5     5     5     5     5     0     0     0     0
     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     0     0     0
     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     0     0
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Luego:

```
>> A=spdiags(B,0:9,10,10);
>> full(A)

ans =

    10     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
     0     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
     0     0     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
     0     0     0     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
     0     0     0     0     6     5     4     3     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     5     4     3     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     4     3     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Para generalizar, tu función podría tomar esta forma:

```
function [A] = P1a(n)
    B = [];
    for i=1:n
        v = 1:n-i+1;
        v(end+1:n)=0;
        v=flip(v);
        B=[B v'];
    end
    A = spdiags(B, 0:(n-1), n, n);
end
```

Aunque más simple parece ser:

```
%no necesita usar spdiags
function [B] = p1A(n)
    B = [];
    for i=1:n
        v = 1:n-i+1;
        v(end+1:n)=0;
        v=flip(v);
        B=[B;v];
    end
end
```